# How to get Intraday backfilled FOREX data programmatically?

Tags: web-services, forex

I've been looking for real time intraday quotes data for major FOREX pairs, backfilled to several days. I want to use it programmatically for Android or web application, therefore a CSV or XML formated webservice would be ideal.

So far I found a few websites by googling such as finam.ru. But it is in Russian and I was not able to find any clearly documented source on exact URL format how to obtain it.

Could someone guide me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the url: http://www.finam.ru/analysis/profile041CA00007/ you can choose the data to export in csv.

You should choose "Мировые валюты" (International Currencies) on the left combobox and you can choose the currency on the right.

Then you click on the button and download a csv file. Here is an example with minute data:

```
http://195.128.78.52/AUDCAD_140501_140526.txt?market=5&em=181410&code=AUDCAD&df=1&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=2&f=AUDCAD_140501_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDCAD&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=2&at=1
```

I have never seen a documentation for it. Just experimented with the date and got the needed period.

You can add the header:`Referer:http://www.finam.ru/analysis/profile2C4A000007/` to get the tick data. The code in C# that allows to bypass the restrictions is at the end of the answer.

In the form the periods are the following:

```
<select id="issuer-profile-export-period" name="p" style="width: 135px; display: none;">
<option value="1">тики</option> ticks
<option value="2">1 мин.</option> 1 minute
<option value="3">5 мин.</option> 5 minutes
<option value="4">10 мин.</option> 10 minutes
<option value="5">15 мин.</option> 15 minutes
<option value="6">30 мин.</option> 30 minutes
<option value="7" selected="selected">1 час</option> 1 hour
<option value="8">1 день</option> 1 day
<option value="9">1 неделя</option> 1 week
<option value="10">1 месяц</option> 1 month
</select>
```

mstimer = 1 - moscow time
mstimer = 0 - not moscow time
f - mane of file

It is most likely that to change the currency you need to change it in three places: em=(these are the codes from the code below), code=, cn=

Currencies:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" index="1" value="181410" class="">Aud/Cad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="2" value="181411" class="">Aud/Chf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="3" value="181418" class="">Aud/Dkk</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="4" value="181408" class="">Aud/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="5" value="181417" class="hover">Aud/Nok</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="6" value="181409" class="">Aud/Nzd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="7" value="181419">Aud/Sek</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="8" value="181416">Aud/Sgd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="9" value="66699">Aud/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="10" value="181389">Cad/Chf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="11" value="181390">Cad/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="12" value="181455">Cad/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="13" value="181403">Chf/Dkk</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="14" value="21084">Chf/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="15" value="181396">Chf/Sgd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="16" value="181454">Chf/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="17" value="181402">Dkk/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="18" value="181414">Eur/Aud</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="19" value="176166">Eur/Byr</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="20" value="181413">Eur/Cad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="21" value="106">Eur/Chf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="22" value="83226">Eur/Cny</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="23" value="88">Eur/Gbp</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="24" value="181407">Eur/Hkd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="25" value="181422">Eur/Huf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="26" value="84">Eur/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="27" value="176172">Eur/Kzt</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="28" value="176177">Eur/Lvl</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="29" value="176179">Eur/Mdl</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="30" value="181401">Eur/Nok</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="31" value="181415">Eur/Nzd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="32" value="66860">Eur/Rub</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="33" value="181406">Eur/Sek</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="34" value="181395">Eur/Sgd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="35" value="176174">Eur/Tjs</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="36" value="176168">Eur/Uah</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="37" value="83">Eur/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="38" value="176170">Eur/Uzs</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="39" value="181412">Gbp/Aud</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="40" value="181388">Gbp/Cad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="41" value="181387">Gbp/Chf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="42" value="181386">Gbp/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="43" value="181400">Gbp/Nok</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="44" value="181405">Gbp/Sek</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="45" value="181394">Gbp/Sgd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="46" value="86">Gbp/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="47" value="181420">Hkd/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="48" value="181421">Huf/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="49" value="181450">Jpy/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="50" value="181385">Mxn/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="51" value="181399">Nok/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="52" value="181392">Nzd/Cad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="53" value="181391">Nzd/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="54" value="181398">Nzd/Sgd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="55" value="181425">Nzd/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="56" value="181423">Pln/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="57" value="176165">Rub/Eur</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="58" value="176176">Rub/Lvl</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="59" value="176164">Rub/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="60" value="181404">Sek/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="61" value="181397">Sgd/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="62" value="181393">Sgd/Usd</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="63" value="176167">Usd/Byr</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="64" value="66700">Usd/Cad</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="65" value="85">Usd/Chf</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="66" value="83225">Usd/Cny</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="67" value="82">Usd/Dem</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="68" value="182106">Usd/Idr</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="69" value="181873">Usd/Inr</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="70" value="87">Usd/Jpy</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="71" value="176173">Usd/Kzt</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="72" value="176178">Usd/Lvl</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="73" value="176180">Usd/Mdl</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="74" value="901">Usd/Rub</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="75" value="176175">Usd/Tjs</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="76" value="176169">Usd/Uah</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="77" value="176171">Usd/Uzs</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="78" value="181426">Xag</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="79" value="181427">Xau</a></li>
<li><a href="#" index="80" value="181424">Zar/Usd</a></li></ul>
```

The only difference in requests that bypass the restrictions and that don't is the header: "Referer:http://www.finam.ru/analysis/profile2C4A000007/"

Here is the link to tick data

```
http://195.128.78.52/AUDJPY_140526_140526.txt?market=5&em=181408&code=AUDJPY&df=26&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=1&f=AUDJPY_140526_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDJPY&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=6&at=1
```

Here are the headers of the original request that worked:

```
Remote Address:195.128.78.52:80
Request URL:http://195.128.78.52/AUDJPY_140526_140526.txt?market=5&em=181408&code=AUDJPY&df=26&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=1&f=AUDJPY_140526_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDJPY&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=6&at=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Host:195.128.78.52
Referer:http://www.finam.ru/analysis/profile2C4A000007/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

Here are the headers of the request that did not work:

```
Remote Address:195.128.78.52:80
Request URL:http://195.128.78.52/AUDJPY_140526_140526.txt?market=5&em=181408&code=AUDJPY&df=26&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=1&f=AUDJPY_140526_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDJPY&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=6&at=1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Host:195.128.78.52
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

The code to bypass restrictions and get the tick data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,it;q=0.2");
            client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://www.finam.ru/analysis/profile2C4A000007/");


            string url = "http://195.128.78.52/AUDJPY_140526_140526.txt?market=5&em=181408&code=AUDJPY&df=26&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=1&f=AUDJPY_140526_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDJPY&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=6&at=1";
            string htmlString = client.DownloadString(url);

            Console.WriteLine(htmlString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. However when I pasted your link on browser, it downloaded CADJPY_140516_140525.txt, with content as follows: Àâòîìàòè÷åñêàÿ (Download-ìåíåäæåðû è ïðîãðàììû ñîáñòâåííîãî èçãîòîâëåíèÿ) çàãðóçêà "òèêîâûõ" äàííûõ íå äîñòóïíà

Comment: Moreover, I cannot write a program to interact with finam web forms. I would need an URL with query strings like the example you gave me. Though it did not work, if it does work, could you explain various paramters passed into the URL string so I can construct my own query?

Comment: Автоматическая (Download-менеджеры и программы собственного изготовления) загрузка "тиковых" данных не доступна Automatic (with download managers and your own programs) download of tick data is forbidden

Comment: It means it checks somewhere if you got the file from the form or not.

Comment: I Changed the link to http://195.128.78.52/AUDCAD_140526_140526.txt?market=5&em=181410&code=AUDCAD&df=26&mf=4&yf=2014&dt=26&mt=4&yt=2014&p=7&f=AUDCAD_140526_140526&e=.txt&cn=AUDCAD&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=0&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=2&at=1  It is hourly data and can probably work as it did not want to give tick data.

Comment: Thank you. The link worked. However, I already have hour data. I could not figure out from just by looking at the link how to get the minute data, which is what I truly want. thanks.

Comment: I have uploaded a link with minutes. I also tried to decypher some of the fields.

Comment: I still can't get the data reliably. The URL you provided seems to be fixed to giving data from 2014-5-1 to 2014-5-26. When I change the parameters, it still returns the same range of data..

Comment: I guess my question is: How do you get the 1-min, 5-min, 10-min price bars for the past X days, where X can be 1, 2, 3, .. 10?